# Xamarin exception when framework callback passes an interface

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind a framework written in Swift to my Xamarin application. The framework has a delegate with the following method:

```
onError(error: IError)
```

IError is a protocol in Swift (4):

```
@objc public protocol IError {
    var message: String { get }
}
```

It's binding, as generated by sharpie and modified by me, looks like this:

```
// @protocol IError
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]  // <- Added by me. Won't compile without it.
[Protocol, Model]
abstract class IError
{
    // @required @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString * _Nonnull message;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("message")]
    string Message { get; }
}
```

When the callback is being called, I get the following error in my application:

> System.MemberAccessException has been thrown
>
> Cannot create an instance of IError because it is an abstract class

Why is my application trying to instantiate IError? isn't the framework supposed to do this? Does it have to do with `[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]`?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57268). You need to declare a bare interface with the same name but starting with 'I' in your binding and then it magically creates a wrapper for the interface which you receive instead of the real object.

The binding now looks like this:

```
//bare interface
interface IIError {}

// @protocol IError
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]  // <- Added by me. Won't compile without 
it.
[Protocol, Model]
abstract class IError
{
// @required @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString * 
_Nonnull message;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("message")]
    string Message { get; }
}
```

The binding for the method then looks like this:

```
[Abstract]
[Export("onError:")]
void OnError(IIError error);
```

**EDIT:**
It seems to also be documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference). Missed it somehow.

Comment: Wow thank you! You saved me a ton of time. I think your answer is easier to understand than the official doc. Couldn't tell that it's related to this error